# $ι:U→V$ is an embedding, $Q:=ιι^*$, $L∈(ℝ^d)$, $Φ∈\text{HS}(U,ℝ^d)$ $⇒$ $\text{tr}LΦ\sqrt Q(Φ\sqrt Q)^*$ doesn't depend on $ι$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace

Let$^1$

- $U$ and $V$ be separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces
- $\iota\in\operatorname{HS}(U,V)$ be a Hilbert-Schmidt embedding
- $Q:=\iota\iota^\ast$
- $u:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ be twice Fréchet differentiable with second Fréchet derivative denoted by ${\rm D}^2u:\mathbb R^d\to\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^d)$, i.e. $${\rm D}^2u(x)y=\nabla^2u(x)y\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in\mathbb R^d$$ where $\nabla^2u(x)$ denotes the Hessian of $u$ at $x\in\mathbb R^d$
- $x\in\mathbb R^d$ and $L:={\rm D}^2u(x)$
- $\Phi\in\operatorname{HS}(U,\mathbb R^d)$ and $B:=\Phi\sqrt Q$

> How can we calculate $\operatorname{tr}LBB^\ast$ and show that it doesn't depend on $\iota$?

I've tried the following: Since $Q$ is nonnegative and symmetric with finite trace, there is an orthonormal basis $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $V$ with $$Qf_n=\lambda_nf_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag 1$$ by the Hilbert-Schmidt theorem. Now, we can show that $$e_n:=\sqrt Qf_n\;\;\;\text{for }n\in N:=\left\{n\in\mathbb N:\lambda_n>0\right\}$$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$. Thus,

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname{tr}LBB^\ast&\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}Bf_n\cdot LBf_n\\
&\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\Phi\sqrt Qf_n\cdot L\Phi\sqrt Qf_n\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt Qf_n\cdot\Phi^\ast L\Phi\sqrt Qf_n\\
&=\sum_{n\in N}e_n\cdot\Phi^\ast L\Phi e_n\\
&\stackrel{\text{def}}=\operatorname{tr}\Phi^\ast L\Phi
\end{split}\tag 2
\end{equation}

So, $\operatorname{tr}LBB^\ast$ doesn't depend on $\iota$ and $$\operatorname{tr}LBB^\ast=\operatorname{tr}\Phi^\ast L\Phi=\operatorname{tr}L\Phi\Phi^\ast\stackrel{\text{def}}=\sum_{i=1}^dL\Phi\Phi^\ast x_i\cdot x_i\tag 3\;,$$ where $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ denotes the Standard basis of $\mathbb R^d$.

> Did I made any mistake so far? If not, can we further simplify the right-hand side of $(3)$?

---

$^1$ Let $\mathfrak L(A,B)$ and $\operatorname{HS}(A,B)$ denote the space of bounded, linear operators and Hilbert-Schmidt Operators, respectively. Moreover, let $\mathfrak L(A):=\mathfrak L(A,A)$.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure of the exact definition of the object you are using, but I will make soame commets anyway.

1) I think there is typo. The sense of the question seems to require $\Phi\in\operatorname{HS}(V,\mathbb R^d)$, and not $\Phi\in\operatorname{HS}(U,\mathbb R^d)$ as you write.

2) $x, u$ ar decorations; all it matters is that $L \in\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^d)$, and $L^*=L$

3) The statement "$e_n:=\sqrt Qf_n\;\;\;\text{for }n\in N:=\left\{n\in\mathbb N:\lambda_n>0\right\}$" looks suspicious: $e_n \in U$, and $\sqrt Qf_n \in V$. There should be a $\iota$ or $\iota^*$ somewhere to place left hand side and right hand side on the same space. The relation 
$$ e_n:=\lambda_n^{-\frac{1}{2}}\iota^*(f_n)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in N:=\left\{n\in\mathbb N:\lambda_n>0\right\}$$
seem to work with the rest of the statement, if my understanding of HS embedding is correct.
With this relation, $\iota(e_n) = \lambda_n^{-\frac{1}{2}}\iota\iota^*(f_n) = \lambda_n^{-\frac{1}{2}}Q(f_n) = \lambda_n^{\frac{1}{2}}f_n, \; \iota^* \iota(e_n) =\lambda_n e_n $ and

$$ \sum_n ||\iota(e_n)||_V ^2 = \sum_n\lambda_n .$$

4) Now lets go over (2) in your proof.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname{tr}LBB^\ast&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt Qf_n\cdot\Phi^\ast L\Phi\sqrt Qf_n\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} <\lambda_n^{\frac{1}{2}} f_n| \Phi^\ast L\Phi \lambda_n^{\frac{1}{2}} f_n>_V\\
&=\sum_{n\in N} <\iota(e_n) | \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota(e_n)>_V \\
&=\sum_{n\in N} \lambda_n^{-1} <\iota \iota^* \iota(e_n) | \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota(e_n)>_V \\
&=\sum_{n\in N} \lambda_n^{-1} < \iota(e_n) | \iota (\iota^* \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota \; e_n) >_V \\
&=\sum_{n\in N} \lambda_n^{-1} <e_n | \iota^* \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota e_n >_{HS} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The trace of $\iota^* \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota $ is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname{tr}\iota^* \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota &=
\sum_{n\in N} \lambda_n^{-1} <e_n , \iota^* \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota \; e_n >_{U} \\
\end{split}\tag{a}
\end{equation}

whereas the trace of $LBB^*$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname{tr}LBB^\ast&=\sum_{n\in N} <\iota(e_n) | \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota(e_n)>_V \\
&=\sum_{n\in N} <e_n | \iota^* \Phi^\ast L\Phi \iota(e_n)>_U \\
\end{split}\tag{b}
\end{equation}

(a) and (b) are different.

It is easy to trace the computations when all spaces are finite dimentional, keeping track of the 3 different dot-products at play (i.e.: the dot product in $U$, then one in $V$, and the HS product induced on $U$ by the HS embedding.

Comment: (1) is not true. Clearly, $Q$ is an operator $V\to V$, but $\sqrt Q$ is an operator $V\to\sqrt QV=\iota U=U$. So, we can choose $\Phi\in\operatorname{HS}(U,\mathbb R^d)$.

Comment: (3) The declaration of $e_n$ is correct as it is written, since $\sqrt Q f_n\in\iota U=U$.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've noticed that $$\operatorname{tr}\Phi^\ast L\Phi=\sum_{i,j=1}^dl_{ij}\langle\Phi^\ast x_i,\Phi^\ast x_j\rangle_U\;,$$ where $L=(l_{ij})\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$, and since $$\Phi^\ast x_i=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(x_i\cdot\Phi e_n))e_n\,,$$ we can conclude that $$\operatorname{tr}\Phi^\ast L\Phi=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[L\Phi e_n\cdot\Phi e_n\right]\;.$$

Comment: For 1), as I said, I was not sure of the definiton of objects involved, and I took $\sqrt Q$ in the standard sense of the square root of a positive semidefinite operator. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @0xbadf00d, you asked if you made any mistake so far, and it is difficult to assess if you did because you do not spell out all details. In your comments you say "$QV=\iota U=U$" , true, but the identifycation of $\iota U=U$ is not canonical ("co-ordenate free", "functorial"). There are 2 different inner products in U, the original one, and the one induced by the embedding. $\{e_n\}$ are orthogonal to each other in both inner products, but their norms are different.

Comment: To compute the trace you have to use the right inner product, and you are switching inner products when you say $\{e_n\}$ are $\mathbf{orthonormal}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43386/discussion-between-victorzurkowski-and-0xbadf00d).

Comment: I'm not switching the inner product, cause the inner product induced by the embedding on $\iota U=U$ is simply $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U$ ($\iota$ is an isometry between $U$ and $\iota U$).

Comment: After my last comment, do you still think $(2)$ in the question is wrong?

Comment: I do. Hopefully someone else will give an answer.

Comment: That's unlikely. Could you please share your doubts? I thought your argument was that the inner products $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U$ and $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_{U_0}$ with $U_0:=\sqrt QV$ are different?

Comment: To clarify, by definition, $$\langle u,v\rangle_{U_0}=\langle Q^{-\frac12}u,Q^{-\frac12}v\rangle_V\;\;\;\text{for all }u,v\in U_0\;.$$ Now it turns out that $$\left\|u\right\|_U=\left\|u\right\|_{U_0}=\left\|\iota u\right\|_{V_0}=\left\|u\right\|_{V_0}\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U_0=U\;,$$ i.e. $\iota$ is an isometry between $U=U_0$ and $V_0$ and hence $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\dot\;\rangle_U=\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\dot\;\rangle_{V_0}$.

Comment: I checked the computations in the as of finite dimensional spaces, and you are right, the dependence on the embedding drops off. $sqrt(Q)$ uses the information on the embedding, but the combination $BB^{\star}$ makes the embedding reference drop.